# JS - очистка памяти (значений)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, возникла такая проблема, пишу на JS недавно, уже много знаю относительно того, что знал, но вот проблема с увеличение кода появилась, заметил то, что например если обновить внутренне страницу (через JS (load, html)), то как-бы все функции всеровно получаются запущенными и в итоге я нажимаю на кнопку - срабатывает клик и выполняется функция аж 3 раза каким-то образом.

**Вопрос собственно:** Можно ли как-то разделить или очищать память после выполнения функции? Вроде есть return и еще что-то с event, но если это то самое - то не умею видимо пользоваться.

Comment: У вас есть ошибки в коде, в частности повторное навешивание обработчиков событий.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, в этом одна из проблем, обработчики были друг в друге

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return false` и `event.preventdefault()` не помогут в этом случае. Но есть такие методы:

**Решение 1. [Off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**

```js
//при загрузке страницы были какие-то обработчики onClick
$("button").click(function(){
   console.log("function1")
})

//...

//через какое-то время
$("button").off('click')//Отключаем все обработчики onClick

$("button").click(function(){
   console.log("function2");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>test</button>
```

**Решение 2.** Назначем обработчики событий только при загрузке.

Мы можем поставить обработчик события на неизменяемого родителя, тогда нам не придется еще раз назначать функции
 после загрузки и добавления контента.

Для этого понадобится [`.on( events, selector, handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) Пример:

```js
//Вешаем обработчик только при загрузке страницы:
$("#main").on("click","button",function(){
   console.log("function1")
})

//...

//через какое-то время добавляется кнопка:
$("#main").append($("<button>test</button>"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
```

Comment: Благодарю, отметил за самый информативный ответ, эти моменты не знал

Answer (score 1):

Статься тебе в помощь.
https://learn.javascript.ru/memory-leaks

если ты делаешь обработчики событий

elem.onclick, то они не очищаются. так-же не очищаются все переменные выше по дереву

```js
f1()
function f1 (){
  var a = 'жру память';
  f2 ()
  function f2 (){
    document.onclick = function () {
      console.log(a)
    }
  }
}
```

Теперь куда бы ты не кликал на документе будет выводится в консоль )))))))

чтоб очистить память:
document.onclick = null;

Comment: как данный ответ относится к вопросу?

Comment: И где тут утечка? Одна единственная переменная в замыкании. Вот если на клик ещё одну такую навешивать...

Comment: Как решение не подойдёт, но как вывод в консоль опробую, тоже спасибо